# Migrate media with alternative text

Tags: migrations, media

I'm trying to import image with new media module on core 8.5.

I've a json source and on my .yml I've:

```
  field_media_image:
    target_id:
      plugin: migration
      migration: immagini
      source: fid
```

This works, immagini is another importer that imports files.

In the new media there is also an "alt" (mandatory) and "title" attribute on the media entity.
But if I try to add something like this, it doesn't work (alt_text is the correct source for alternative text). The media is created but is not referenced to the correct id:

```
  field_media_image:
    alt: alt_text
    target_id:
      plugin: migration
      migration: immagini
      source: fid
```

How should I pass the alt attribute to this field?
I also tried to use a syntax like:

```
  field_media_image:
    target_id:
      plugin: migration
      migration: immagini
      source: fid
  'field_media_image/alt': alt_text
```

But it doesn't work, the media is created but there is no reference to the correct id.

Answer (score 2):

`field_media_image/alt` belongs in the `immagini` migration, not in the node migration.

In migration that creates the media item (destination plugin entity:media) you can map the media item's fields:

```
  # Image field see media_entity.bundle.image.yml.
  field_media_image/target_id: fid
  field_media_image/alt: field_file_image_alt_text/0/value
  field_media_image/title: field_file_image_title_text/0/value

  # Description field.
  field_description: field_image_description
  # Caption field.
  field_caption: field_caption

destination:
  plugin: entity:media
```

See https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/migrating-drupal-7-file-entities-drupal-8-media-entities